# Cannot define font color in fontspec

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I try to define a custom font using `fontspec` package. I would also like to define the color of the font via `\defaultfontfeatures`, however it makes no difference. When I change color using `\textcolor{}{}` it does work. Does anyone have a clue why it is not working? Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\defaultfontfeatures[AnonymousPro]
{
    Color = red                           ,
    Extension      = .ttf                       ,
    UprightFont    = ZapfChanceryCTT            ,
}
\newfontfamily\anonymous{AnonymousPro}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

{\anonymous \lipsum[1]}

{\anonymous \textcolor{red}{\lipsum[1]}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Move the loading of `xcolor` package _before_ using `Color` option.

Comment: You should get lots of warnings in the log.

Comment: Thank you, muzimuzhi Z ! Your suggestion worked perfectly!